# JTextPane - get start position of a displayed line

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I've a JTextPane that is used to show a text file. The text appears as follows 
`Line 1`
`Line 2`
`Line 3`

What I want to get is the start index of the line where my caret is currently positioned. Is there a simple method in JTextPane that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this:

```
JTextComponent testingArea = new JTextPane();
....
int caretPos = testingArea.getCaretPosition();
int rowNum = (caretPos == 0) ? 1 : 0;
for (int offset = caretPos; offset > 0;) {
    offset = Utilities.getRowStart(textArea, offset) - 1;
    rowNum++;
}
System.out.println("Row: " + rowNum);
```

Comment: Thanks David! This helped me a lot. I didn't have any idea about the `Utilities` class and I found a lot many useful methods in here. +1 for all your help!